# How many permutations of an array containing integers 1 and -1 are possible such that the running sum is always strictly positive. Given N > M

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, combinatorics

An array of length N + M consists of integers -1 and 1(N 1's and M -1's).
**Given: N > M**

How many distinct permutations are possible such that the running sum is always strictly positive or sum[i] = arr[0] + ..... + arr[i] > 0 for all i in [0, N + M - 1]

**Example:**

For N =  4 and M = 3, arr = [1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1] is one such permutation whereas, arr = [1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1] is not valid as sum[1] = arr[0] + arr[1] = 0

To solve this I used a recursive approach that counts through all such possible permutations:

```
def solve(N, M, n = 0, m = 0, flagA = 1):
    # N, M = Number of 1's and -1's left
    # n, m = Number of 1's and -1's counted
    if M == 0:
        return 1
    perms = 0
    if flagA:
        for a in range(1, N + 1):
            perms += solve(N - a, M, n + a, m, 0)
    else:
        for b in range(1, n):
            if b > M or m + b >= n:
                break
            perms += solve(N, M - b, n, m + b, 1)
    return perms
```

While this works for smaller values of N and M < 25. It gets very slow for higher values of N + M.
I tried using a memoization matrix ((N + 1) x (M + 1) x 2) which would work for N + M <= 500 but fails for N + M > 600 or so. In the following code, mem has been initialized with all elements = -1 except: mem[i][0][0] = mem[i][0][1] = 1 for all i in [0, N].

```
def solve(N, M, n = 0, m = 0, flagA = 1):
    global mem
    if mem[N][M][flagA] != -1:
        return mem[N][M][flagA]
    p = 0
    if flagA:
        for a in range(1, N + 1):
            p += solve(N - a, M, n + a, m, 0)
    else:
        for b in range(1, n):
            if b > M or m + b >= n:
                break
            p += solve(N, M - b, n, m + b, 1)
    mem[N][M][flagA] = p
    return p
```

It would be great if someone could suggest a better approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the answer for this  [1, 1, -1, 1]?

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) out.

Comment: @nomanpouigt, Answer would be 2 for the case.

Comment: @user58697, Thanks! That solved the problem.